# ERROR: function gen_random_uuid() does not exist

Tags: postgresql

I use PostgreSQL 12.12. I want to create a table using:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS lists
(
    id uuid DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
    ...........
}
```

When I run the code I get error:

```
ERROR:  function gen_random_uuid() does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT gen_random_uuid()
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
SQL state: 42883
Character: 8
```

Do you know what is the proper way to implement this?

Comment: `gen_random_uuid()` as a standard Postgres function was not added until version 13. You will need to use the contrib extension [pgcrypto](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/pgcrypto.html) or  [uuid-ossp](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/uuid-ossp.html) in particular `uuid_generate_v4()`

Comment: Is it possible to add the extension and use `gen_random_uuid()`?

Comment: Yes, it depends on how you installed Postgres. More information is needed 1) OS and version. 2) How did you install Postgres?

Comment: Don't ask the same question twice. It is annoying.